# Create DataFrame from subarrays of existing Series object

Tags: python, pandas

Could you suggest the method to create DataFrame from Series like I have described below:
Input Series

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Wanted DataFrame:

```
    x   y   z
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
3   4   5   6
```

Of course I could do it by using loop but I hope there is way to do it more elegantly.

Comment: Is the number of columns always 3?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that's what you're looking for, but here's a pretty trivial way to do that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": s[:-2].values, "y": s[1:-1].values, "z": s[2:].values} )
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
```